# Shared resources between subdomains

Tags: javascript, html, css, dns

I have subdomains to my web site as follows

Language domains

en.ice-os.com

ja.ice-os.com

mtrn.ice-os.com

zing.ice-os.com

Mercurial

hg.ice-os.com

Images

images.ice-os.com

how can I access images from the other subdomains from say en.ice-os.com

in a relative way with out having to type full path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative host names is not a feature the the URL specification has ever supported so unfortunately there is no way you can really achieve this in HTML.

My only suggestion is to create a single shared assets domain such as assets.ice-os.com and use that across all your sites.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with relative URIs, you have to explicitly state the part you want to change and everything to the right of it.

In this case, the first section to the left of the left most bit that is changing is the scheme, so you can use a scheme relative URI.

```
//www.example.com/foo/bar/
```

That will save you `http:`, but you can't save anything further.